# WooCommerce One Page Checkout - Hide Product Attribute Colon

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm currently using [WooCommerce OnePage CheckOut](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-one-page-checkout/)
I'd like to remove the ["attribute :" text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFvty.jpg) from the product list.

1. I copied **product-list.php**
   FROM: "/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-one-page-checkout/templates/checkout/"
   TO: "/public_html/wp-content/themes/my-theme-child/woocommerce/checkout/**product-list.php**"
2. Modified the "/public_html/wp-content/themes/my-theme-child/woocommerce/checkout/**product-list.php**" file

FROM:

```html
<span class="attributes"><?php echo esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', $attribute_string, $product->get_variation_attributes(), $product ) ); ?></span>
```

TO:

```html
<span class="attributes"><?php echo esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', str_replace ("attribute: ","",$attribute_string), $product->get_variation_attributes(), $product ) ); ?></span>
```

3. Once I saved the file, seems the changes not reflected on the page?

Did I miss anything here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be caching issue *sigh*
All good now

---

Another option is to update `/wp-content/themes/my-theme-child/functions.php`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute_label', 'remove_attribute_label');
function remove_attribute_label() {
  return "";
}
```

But with this option, the [colon still exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCiLV.jpg)...